# How do I allow pandas to process quote characters without recognizing them as EOF?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm trying to process a CSV file with pandas. One of my fields is book titles. Some of them have a comma in the title. I need to escape the comma with quotes in order for the INSERT statement to execute correctly in postgresql. However, when parsing the file, pandas sees "" in the last line as EOF. How can I get pandas to process the "" without recognizing this as EOF?

Here are the first four lines of my csv file with headers. The issue is with I"," Robot. (spaces in between lines added here for readability):

```
    isbn,title,author_id,year_id

    INSERT INTO books (isbn, title, author_id, year_id) VALUES ('0380795272','Krondor: The Betrayal','610','135');

    INSERT INTO books (isbn, title, author_id, year_id) VALUES ('1416949658','The Dark Is Rising','1145','110');

    INSERT INTO books (isbn, title, author_id, year_id) VALUES ('1857231082','The Black Unicorn ','1208','124');

    INSERT INTO books (isbn, title, author_id, year_id) VALUES ('0553803700','I"," Robot','230','87');
```

Here is the line of code that is trying to parse (I tried setting quoting to none. I also tried setting quotechar="", but everything seems to just cause the parsing to omit the "" which causes an error on the db when trying to execute the INSERT statement.

```
    file=pd.read_csv('import_books.csv',delimiter=',',quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
```

I need it to process the title in that last line as 'I"," Robot'

Thanks,

-John

Comment: Just to be clear, the sql is in the csv file as well? or just the values?

Comment: Correct. The sql command is in the csv as well

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

with open('import_books.csv', 'r') as file:
    data = file.read()

regex = re.compile(r".*\n.*VALUES \('(\d+)','(.+?)','(\d+)','(\d+)'.*")
df = pd.DataFrame(regex.findall(data), columns=['isbn', 'title', 'author_id','year_id'])


     isbn            title            author_id     year_id
0   0380795272  Krondor: The Betrayal    610         135
1   1416949658  The Dark Is Rising      1145         110
2   1857231082  The Black Unicorn       1208         124
3   0553803700  I"," Robot               230         87
```

Since all that sql is included in your csv, I recommend just finding the values you want with regex, then making it a dataframe. The " is included in 'I"," Robot'

Comment: Thanks. I played around with what you posted and got it figured out. First thing, The entry in the db ended up as I"," Robot. I ended up dropping the "" and using a df.to_sql("books", engine). Which entered everything perfectly. Thanks a bunch!!